# How do I cure a call to the AWS Java SDK DynamoDB resulting in an ExpiredTokenException?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a long running AWS Java SDK DynamoDB application which behaves normally when I start it up. However, after some number of hours (around 12), I start receiving the same `Exception` over and over again with ANY call to the DynamoDB API. If I restart the server, the `Exception` disappears...only to reappear again later.

The exact `ExpiredTokenException` error text is:
*The security token included in the request is expired (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: **ExpiredTokenException**; Request ID: DEMTN0Q5BMPH5IQD9TUQMNO5SFVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Summary:**
Pass an instance of `AWSCredentialsProvider` (as opposed to `AWSCredentials`) to `AmazonDynamoDBClient`'s constructor as this enables automatic refreshing of expired `AWSCredentials` (if the particular `AWSCredentialsProvider` has implemented the refresh functionality...which is the case with all the standard AWS provided ones).

**Details:**
To resolve the AWS Java SDK DynamoDB related ExpiredTokenException which starts with the prefix "*The security token included in the request is expired (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ExpiredTokenException; Request ID: ...*", you must alter your code to provide an instance of `AWSCredentialsProvider` (and stop using an instance of `AWSCredentials` - i.e. sans the "Provider" suffix) to the `AmazonDynamoDBClient`'s constructor. By handing the `AmazonDynamoDBClient`'s constructor an instance of `AWSCredentialsProvider`, you give it the ability to "automatically refresh the credentials" if/when the `AWSCredentials` expire (which I found in this [AWS forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=463216) which requires an account to access).

To provide an explicit example in code, here's a generalization of what the code is producing the `ExpiredTokenException`:

```
AWSCredentialsProvider aWSCredentialsProvider =
  new SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider();
    //the above line may be substituted for any valid
    //*Provider implementation
AWSCredentials aWSCredentials =
  aWSCredentialsProvider.getCredentials();
AmazonDynamoDBClient amazonDynamoDBClient =
  new AmazonDynamoDBClient(aWSCredentials);
...
amazonDynamoDBClient.listTables();
  //the above line is where the ExpiredTokenException is eventually thrown
```

And here is a generalization of the code eliminating the `ExpiredTokenException`:

```
AWSCredentialsProvider aWSCredentialsProvider =
  new SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider();
    //substitute the above line for any valid *Provider implementation
AmazonDynamoDBClient amazonDynamoDBClient =
  new AmazonDynamoDBClient(aWSCredentialsProvider);
    //the above line is now passing an instance of AWSCredentialsProvider
    //as opposed to AWSCredentials
...
amazonDynamoDBClient.listTables();
  //the above line is now enabled, via the AWSCredentialsProvider, to 
  //automatically refresh the AWSCredentials if/when they have expired
```

Given how much I climbed all over the AWS Java SDK Javadocs and their provided examples (upon which I based most of my own code), I didn't once notice this specific nuance called out. Hence, the very detailed answer I'm providing for those who come after me (which likely will include myself, LOL).

Comment: Thank you for posting this.